# Postman getting response 400 Bad Request

Tags: json, rest, authentication, postman

I'm trying to access an API using Postman to get a response using basic authentication, but when I submit the data, it gives me the dreaded 400 error, which apparently indicates that some headers aren't set up properly.

Here's the API info:

```
Request

Endpoint: {loginUrl}
Data to submit: an email and a password
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: {baseUrl}
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 68

{
    "email": "{email}",
    "password": "{password}"
}
```

And in response, I should get an encrypted token in form of JSON, instead I'm getting this error.

Here are the postman screenshots:

[image: Postman_01]

[image: Postman_02]

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the request body look like? What are you posting? What does it expect? Do you have the Auth header set and you’re posting the username and password? Rather than explaining what’s in Postman, might be worth just posting an image of the set up.

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re sending the Content-Length header in the request?

Comment: Here are the screenshots from Postman

https://i.imgur.com/lLnbSJ4.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/Ox2eOIm.jpg

This is an assignment and I'm still new to REST, all the info I've been given is already covered up there.

One of the headers specified was Content-Length in the API docs, so I guess that's why I put it there.

Comment: I would suggest that you update the question with those images and not add them into the comments. Then you can reformat the wording.

Comment: Ok, I guess this will make it easier to read. Any suggestions regarding the problem itself?

Comment: The `Basic` header is just a base64 encoded value so showing it in your image is not really 'Secret' - Basically, anyone can see your username and password.

Comment: I just ran into this, and it was due to Postman setting the 'Host' header to 'calculate-on-send' (or whatever). I had to turn that off, put my own 'Host' header, and put the domain of my test server. Then it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the lack of details it's difficult to offer a specific answer but I can offer something that you can try - The `Request` data you posted in the question looks like you should be adding:

```
{
    "email": "{email}",
    "password": "{password}"
}
```

In the `Body` section of the request but your images don't show that you've added that to the `Body` on *any* request, you've added it as a `Auth` header instead, so remove that before trying again. I'm not sure of the need to add the `Content-Length` header as that will change for different username and password combinations in the payload or for the length of the response.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same issue and i updated my postman header with the below image. And issue solved.
[image]

Comment: It wotks for me after updatting the Content-Type . Now i will like to know when to use application/json as value for the Content-Type ? I receiveid a posaman collection from my team with the application/json as value

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone finds this helpful, I ran into the same issue and the culprit turned out to be missing headers. I knew I needed the `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header, which I already had in place, but I didn't know that I was missing two other headers.

**The solution for me** was also adding the `"Content-Length"` and `"Host"` headers in Postman.

I see some others have questioned the need for the `"Content-Length"` header, but in my case, the minimum three needed were `"Content-Type"`, `"Content-Length"`, and `"Host"` or it would always fail.

Comment: You saved my day. After reactivating the hidden headers, it worked like a charm. I should have google earlier. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I only needed Content-Length (I already used Content-Type).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,and I discovered was sending a json body from postman while a text option was selected instead of a json.[image: A screenshot showing different options in postman]

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue many times, just check the HOST header like they are saying above

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue. it got resolved when i called my placeholder as a tuple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).